# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "FUNCTION"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search

I am following [Optimizing Full Text Search in Django](https://findwork.dev/blog/optimizing-postgres-full-text-search-in-django/) article and at some point the article says:

> In order to add a trigger we need to craft a manual Django migration.
>   This will add the trigger function and update all of our Pages rows to
>   ensure the trigger is fired and content_search is populated at
>   migration time for our existing records.

```
from django.db import migrations
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('web', '0002_auto_20200115_1401')
    ]
    migration = '''
        CREATE TRIGGER content_search_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON web_page FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION
        tsvector_update_trigger(content_search, 'pg_catalog.english', content);

        -- Force triggers to run and populate the text_search column.
        UPDATE web_page set ID = ID;
    '''
    reverse_migration = '''
        DROP TRIGGER content_search ON web_page;
    '''
    operations = [migrations.RunSQL(migration, reverse_migration)]
```

when I run the migration I get this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "FUNCTION"

One difference of my `settings.py` from the tutorial article is that it uses `django.db.backends.postgresql` as database engine and I use `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` 
What can be the problem here and more importantly how can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use `PROCEDURE` instead of `FUNCTION`.

```
from django.db import migrations
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('web', '0002_auto_20200115_1401')
    ]
    migration = '''
        CREATE TRIGGER content_search_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON web_page FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
        tsvector_update_trigger(content_search, 'pg_catalog.english', content);

        -- Force triggers to run and populate the text_search column.
        UPDATE web_page set ID = ID;
    '''
    reverse_migration = '''
        DROP TRIGGER content_search ON web_page;
    '''
    operations = [migrations.RunSQL(migration, reverse_migration)]
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. Is this because of the database engine difference? Specific to psycopg2-binary? I'll accept this answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Nope. I did a search for how to create a trigger in postgres and you use `CREATE FUNCTION` to create the function, but `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` to call that function as a part of a trigger. This is purely a postgres syntax issue.